# How to construct repeated loop in R for 6000 iterations?

Tags: r

At first step, I want to generate a series (more specifically; GARCH (1, 1)), and the estimated it with four different estimation methods (let’s say, M1, M2, M3, M4).

In addition, I want to repeat this process over 6000 times with saving results of each repetition. 
I have done it one by one, but unable to construct a loop.

Comment: You are looking for `help(replicate)` it seems.

Comment: Can you post sample code of what you have tried one by one? Please include calls to `library(pkgname)` if you load non base R packages.

Comment: #Simulation Generation
#specify GARCH(1,1) model
garch11.spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(0,0)), distribution.model="std", fixed.pars=list(mu = 0, omega=0.01, alpha1=0.1, beta1 = 0.1, shape=2.5))
class(garch11.spec)
garch11.spec
#set.seed(123)
garch11.sim = ugarchpath(garch11.spec, n.sim=1000)
class(garch11.sim)
slotNames(garch11.sim)
names(garch11.sim@path)
write.csv(garch11.sim@path,file="garch_norm_1.csv")
ABC1=read.table("garch_norm_1.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

Comment: # M1
addPriorConditions <- function(psi){psi[2] + psi[3] < 1}
MCMC <- bayesGARCH(ABC1[1:1000, 3:3], lambda = 0.01, delta = 2, control = list(n.chain = 1, l.chain = 5000, start.val=c(0.01,0.03,0.5,20),                    addPriorConditions = addPriorConditions))
smpl1 <- formSmpl(MCMC, l.bi = 50)
summary(smpl1)

Comment: #M3
fit1 <- FitMCMC(spec = spec, data = ABC1[1:1000, 3:3], ctr = list(n.burn = 500L, n.mcmc = 5000L, n.thin = 1L, do.adapt = TRUE, acc.rate = 0.6))
summary(fit1)

Comment: cods are too long, therefore, I am posted it step by step, even codes of M2 are too long that can not be posted.

Comment: library(xts)
library(digest)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(jsonlite)
library(rugarch)
library(car)
library(FinTS)
library(bayesGARCH)
library(MSGARCH)
library(DEoptim)
library(mcmc)
library(nloptr)